# What is JNDI? What is its basic use? When is it used?

Tags: jndi

- What is *JNDI*?
- What is its basic use?
- When is it used?

Comment: See personal blog post for definition and use cases: http://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.com/2013/01/what-is-jndi-spi-cci-ldap-and-jca.html

Comment: December 2021 checking in ... you don't want to know our opinion of JNDI :)

Answer (score 304):

> What is JNDI ?

It stands for [Java Naming and Directory Interface](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-137536.html).

> What is its basic use?

JNDI allows distributed applications to look up services in an abstract, resource-independent way.

> When it is used?

The most common use case is to set up a database connection pool on a Java EE application server. Any application that's deployed on that server can gain access to the connections they need using the JNDI name `java:comp/env/FooBarPool` without having to know the details about the connection.

This has several advantages:

1. If you have a deployment sequence where apps move from `devl->int->test->prod` environments, you can use the same JNDI name in each environment and hide the actual database being used. Applications don't have to change as they migrate between environments.
2. You can minimize the number of folks who need to know the credentials for accessing a production database. Only the Java EE app server needs to know if you use JNDI.

Comment: so this is basically a safer alternative to having a properties file with your jdbc connection info?

Comment: @grinch: Essentially yes. It is safer, and more standardized, thus makes deployment easier (no need to guess what the name of the properties file must be etc.).

Comment: What then the difference between using environment variables and JNDI? Is it similar concept?

Answer (score 124):

> What is JNDI ?

The Java Naming and Directory Interface<sup>TM</sup> (JNDI) is an application programming interface (API) that provides naming and directory functionality to applications written using the Java<sup>TM</sup> programming language. It is defined to be independent of any specific directory service implementation. Thus a variety of directories(new, emerging, and already deployed) can be accessed in a common way.

> What is its basic use?

Most of it is covered in the above answer but I would like to provide architecture here so that above will make more sense.

[image]

To use the JNDI, you must have the JNDI classes and one or more service providers. The Java 2 SDK, v1.3 includes three service providers for the following naming/directory services:

1. Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP)
2. Common Object Request Broker Architecture (CORBA) Common Object Services (COS) name service
3. Java Remote Method Invocation (RMI) Registry

So basically you create objects and register them on the directory services which you can later do lookup and execute operation on.

Answer (score 47):

JNDI in layman's terms is basically an Interface for being able to get instances of internal/External resources such as

```
  javax.sql.DataSource, 
  javax.jms.Connection-Factory,
  javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory,
  javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory,
  javax.mail.Session, java.net.URL,
  javax.resource.cci.ConnectionFactory,
```

or any other type defined by a JCA resource adapter.
It provides a syntax in being able to create access whether they are internal or external. i.e (comp/env in this instance means where component/environment, there are lots of other syntax):

```
jndiContext.lookup("java:comp/env/persistence/customerDB");
```

Comment: This is only part of the picture. JNDI lets you look up Java objects - they can be resources like a DataSource, or something else, even plain `java.lang.String` for configuration information.

Answer (score 21):

**JNDI Overview**

> JNDI is an API specified in Java
>   technology that provides naming and
>   directory functionality to
>   applications written in the Java
>   programming language. It is designed
>   especially for the Java platform using
>   Java's object model. Using JNDI,
>   applications based on Java technology
>   can store and retrieve named Java
>   objects of any type. In addition, JNDI
>   provides methods for performing
>   standard directory operations, such as
>   associating attributes with objects
>   and searching for objects using their
>   attributes.
>
> JNDI is also defined independent of
>   any specific naming or directory
>   service implementation. It enables
>   applications to access different,
>   possibly multiple, naming and
>   directory services using a common API.
>   Different naming and directory service
>   providers can be plugged in seamlessly
>   behind this common API. This enables
>   Java technology-based applications to
>   take advantage of information in a
>   variety of existing naming and
>   directory services, such as LDAP, NDS,
>   DNS, and NIS(YP), as well as enabling
>   the applications to coexist with
>   legacy software and systems.
>
> Using JNDI as a tool, you can build
>   new powerful and portable applications
>   that not only take advantage of Java's
>   object model but are also
>   well-integrated with the environment
>   in which they are deployed.

[Reference](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/overview-142035.html)

Answer (score 13):

**What is JNDI ?**

JNDI stands for Java Naming and Directory Interface. It comes standard with J2EE.

**What is its basic use?**

With this API, you can access many types of data, like objects, devices, files of naming and directory services, eg. it is used by EJB to find remote objects. JNDI is designed to provide a common interface to access existing services like DNS, NDS, LDAP, CORBA and RMI.

**When it is used?**

You can use the JNDI to perform naming operations, including read operations and operations for updating the namespace. The following operations are described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ops/index.html).

Answer (score 13):

I will use one example to explain how JNDI can be used to configure database without any application developer knowing username and password of the database.

1) We have configured the data source in JBoss server's **standalone-full.xml**. Additionally, we can configure pool details also.

```
 <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/DEV.DS" pool-name="DEV" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@<IP>:1521:DEV</connection-url>
                <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                <driver>oracle</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>usname</user-name>
                    <password>pass</password>
                    </security>
                    <security>

 <security-domain>encryptedSecurityDomain</security-domain>
                    </security>

                <validation>
                    <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                    <background-validation-millis>1</background-validation-millis>
                </validation>
                <statement>
                    <prepared-statement-cache-size>0</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                    <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
                    </pool>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
```

[image]

Now, this jndi-name and its associated datasource object  will be available for our application.application.

2) We can retrieve this datasource object using JndiDataSourceLookup class.

[image]

Spring will instantiate the datasource bean, after we provide the jndi-name.

Now, we can change the pool size, user name or password as per our environment or requirement, but it will not impact the application.

**Note** : encryptedSecurityDomain, we need to configure it separately in JBoss server like

```
<security-domain name="encryptedSecurityDomain" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="org.picketbox.datasource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="username" value="<usernamefordb>"/>
                            <module-option name="password" value="894c8a6aegc8d028ce169c596d67afd0"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
```

This is one of the use cases. Hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 11):

The best explanation to me is given [here](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/what-is-jndi-spi-cci-ldap-and-jca.html)

**What is JNDI**

> It is an API to providing access to a directory service, that is, a **service mapping name (strings) with objects, reference to remote objects or simple data**. This is called
>   binding. *The set of bindings is called the context*. Applications use the JNDI interface to access resources.
>
> To put it very simply, it is like a hashmap with a String key and Object values representing resources on the web.

**What Issues Does JNDI Solve**

> Without JNDI, the location or access information of remote resources would have to be hard-coded in applications or made available in a configuration. Maintaining this information is quite tedious and error prone.
>
> If a resources has been relocated on another server, with another IP address, for example, all applications using this resource would have to be updated with this new information. With JNDI, this is not necessary. Only the corresponding resource binding has to be updated. Applications can still access it with its name and the relocation is transparent.

Answer (score 8):

A naming service associates names with objects and finds objects based on their given names.(RMI registry is a good example of a naming service.) JNDI provides a common interface to many existing naming services, such as LDAP, DNS.

Without JNDI, the location or access information of remote resources would have to be hard-coded in applications or made available in a configuration. Maintaining this information is quite tedious and error prone.

Answer (score 4):

I am just curious why the [official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/getStarted/overview/index.html) are so ignored which elaborate the details meticulously already.

But if you'd like to understand the cases, please refer to [*duffymo's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4365766/2361308).

> The Java Naming and Directory Interface<sup>TM</sup> (JNDI) is an application programming interface (API) that provides naming and directory functionality to applications written using the Java<sup>TM</sup> programming language. It is defined to be independent of any specific directory service implementation. Thus a variety of directories--new, emerging, and already deployed--can be accessed in a common way.

And its architecture

[image]

And normally [how you use it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/overview/event.html).

Comment: `I am just curious why the official docs are so ignored which elaborate the details meticulously already`
Maybe because they don't explain in a sufficient way that regular people can understand?

Comment: More votes on this comment above than this answer. @Hearen - I think you know why official docs are useless

Answer (score 1):

The Java Naming and Directory InterfaceTM (JNDI) is an application programming interface (API) that provides naming and directory functionality to applications written using the JavaTM programming language. It is defined to be independent of any specific directory service implementation. Thus a variety of directories--new, emerging, and already deployed--can be accessed in a common way.

While JNDI plays less of a role in lightweight, containerized Java applications such as Spring Boot, there are other uses. Three Java technologies that still use JNDI are JDBC, EJB, and JMS. All have a wide array of uses across Java enterprise applications.

For example, a separate DevOps team may manage environment variables such as username and password for a sensitive database connection in all environments. A JNDI resource can be created in the web application container, with JNDI used as a layer of consistent abstraction that works in all environments.

This setup allows developers to create and control a local definition for development purposes while connecting to sensitive resources in a production environment through the same JNDI name.

reference :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/overview/index.html