# Why Use JNDI to access DNS/LDAP/EJB?

Tags: java, dns, ldap, ejb, jndi

While searching for benefits of JNDI, I came across many [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365621/what-is-jndi-what-is-its-basic-use-when-it-is-used)s where it was mentioned that it helps to switch between different environments without changing the application. But why is JNDI used for DNS/LDAP/EJB access? Is it for the same reason or are there additional benefits when it comes to those technolgoies?

Answer (score 1):

Because it's one API instead of three, and you left out RMI and CosNAMING which makes five.

Comment: But is it meaningful to access different types of objects with a single API if we don't plan to swap the technologies? What I mean to say is there would be no scenario where we swap EJB with LDAP. So is having a single API to access both the technologies meaningful?

Comment: Is it meaningful to write five APIs when one will do? Consider what life would be like if we had different I/O APIs for files, sockets, keyboards, ... Ockham's Razor applies. There doesn't need to be any intention to swap providers to justify JNDI.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I think about JNDI; it's an interface (actually more than one) that offers several directory services (e.g. to discover and to lookup an object by name). 
Like any interface, you can have different implementations (LDAP, DNS, etc) and you can to use what is more suitable for solving your problem. 
The design benefits are the ones related to programming against the interface(if you change the implementation the client code that use the API don't needs to change)

Comment: Actually the JDK provides five or six implementations.