# Remove JNDI from Spring initialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jndi

I'm loading Spring application in maven tomcat plugin. I'm not using Spring boot.

On loading I'm getting debug logs of failing to load JNDI properties, for example:

```
[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [server_useforwardheaders]
[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [server_useforwardheaders] threw NamingException with message: Name [server_useforwardheaders] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [server_useforwardheaders].. Returning null.
[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/server.USE-FORWARD-HEADERS]
[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/server.USE-FORWARD-HEADERS] not found - trying original name [server.USE-FORWARD-HEADERS]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [server.USE-FORWARD-HEADERS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [server.USE-FORWARD-HEADERS].
[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [server.USE-FORWARD-HEADERS]
[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [server.USE-FORWARD-HEADERS] threw NamingException with message: Name [server.USE-FORWARD-HEADERS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [server.USE-FORWARD-HEADERS].. Returning null.
[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/server_USE-FORWARD-HEADERS]
[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/server_USE-FORWARD-HEADERS] not found - trying original name [server_USE-FORWARD-HEADERS]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [server_USE-FORWARD-HEADERS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [server_USE-FORWARD-HEADERS].
[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [server_USE-FORWARD-HEADERS]
[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [server_USE-FORWARD-HEADERS] threw NamingException with message: Name [server_USE-FORWARD-HEADERS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [server_USE-FORWARD-HEADERS].. Returning null.
[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/server.USE_FORWARD_HEADERS]
[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/server.USE_FORWARD_HEADERS] not found - trying original name [server.USE_FORWARD_HEADERS]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [server.USE_FORWARD_HEADERS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [server.USE_FORWARD_HEADERS].
[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [server.USE_FORWARD_HEADERS]
[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [server.USE_FORWARD_HEADERS] threw NamingException with message: Name [server.USE_FORWARD_HEADERS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [server.USE_FORWARD_HEADERS].. Returning null.
[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/server_USE_FORWARD_HEADERS]
[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/server_USE_FORWARD_HEADERS] not found - trying original name [server_USE_FORWARD_HEADERS]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [server_USE_FORWARD_HEADERS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [server_USE_FORWARD_HEADERS].
[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [server_USE_FORWARD_HEADERS]
```

Can I disable/ignore JNDI in my spring projects?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring boot embedded tomcat logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48312851/spring-boot-embedded-tomcat-logs)

Comment: @ArunKumar I'm not using Spring boot

Comment: @ArunKumar I don't need `log4j-jul` library, `spring.jndi.ignore=true` fix my issue (not found in post)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a good read: [what is JNDI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21227726/6090738)

> Basic use of JNDI is to allows distributed applications to look up
>   services in an abstract, resource-independent way.

---

**To disable JNDI**

create a `spring.properties` file in `src/main/resources` (ignore if already created) and add this value `spring.jndi.ignore=true`